# Laravel resource controller and model the same for multiple databases

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, connection, crud

Is there any way I can use the same controller and model for multiple databases?

For example I have a `Product` model, and a `ProductController` (CRUD resource controller with `index,show,store,update,destroy`). The databases,models and controllers are identical.

The only way I found to change the connection is in the model `protected $connection = 'connection_name';`
But then I would need to duplicate the ProductController for each model.

I was thinking  to make `ProductController` as `BaseProductController` and extend it for every database but I cannot figure out how to set the connection.

Comment: Even if that's possible it's a bad practice, bad idea and it's not preferred way

Comment: Why should I maintain two models and controllers for two exactly the same databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Dependency Injection on your Product model with a `resolving` hook

In a service provider:

```php
use App\Product;

$this->app->resolving(Product::class, function ($product, $app) {
    $request = $app['request'];
    if ($request->isConnection1()) {
        $product->setConnection('connection1');
    }
    elseif ($request->isConnection2()) {
        $product->setConnection('connection2');
    }
});
```

My example obviously does not work because I don't know your context, but it shows you the way of thinking.

Another way would be to add a middleware to your routes around `ProductController` which sets the DB default connection (used by your models when it's not specified)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Database\ConnectionResolverInterface as DatabaseManager;

class SwitchConnection
{
    protected $dbManager;

    public function __construct(DatabaseManager $dbManager)
    {
        $this->dbManager = $dbManager;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, string $connection)
    {
        $this->dbManager->setDefaultConnection($connection);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

By the way, if you alias this middleware as `switch.connection` and add `switch.connection:connection1` to a route's middlewares, it will automatically switch, and therefore you can use the same controller.

Comment: The middlware works only on index() method. On methods where I load the model as an argument like: `public function destroy(Product $product)
    {
        $delete = $product->delete();
        return $this->sendResponse([], 'product deleted successfully.');
    }` is not working